# Iterating over SQL Objects not working as expected

Tags: powershell

The following code I have is fetching data from SQL however the -ne operator is not working correctly when I have more than one object in $teamConfig.

The following Code outputs the following:

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team1'
        TeamEmail = 'team1@domain.tld'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team3'
        TeamEmail = 'team1@domain.tld'
    }
)

$query = "select * from INCAutomation"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'AyushTest'

foreach ($item in $teamConfig) {
    $teamsExcluded = $results | Where-Object TeamName -ne $item.TeamName | Select TeamName
}

$teamsExcluded
```

Result:

```
TeamName
--------
Team1
Team1
Team1
Team1
Team2
Team2
Team2
```

After removing Team3 from the $teamConfig (example) I get the following desired output:

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team1'
        TeamEmail = 'team1@domain.tld'
    }
)

$query = "select * from INCAutomation"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'AyushTest'

foreach ($item in $teamConfig) {
    $teamsExcluded = $results | Where-Object TeamName -ne $item.TeamName | Select TeamName
}

$teamsExcluded
```

Result:

```
TeamName
--------
Team2
Team2
Team2
```

I've been stuck on this one for a little while, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single pipeline with the [`-notIn` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-notin), combined with [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), in which case you don't need a `foreach` loop:

```sh
$teamsExcluded = $results | 
  Where-Object TeamName -notin $teamConfig.TeamName | 
    Select TeamName
```

The above is not only more efficient, it also avoids the logical problem with your solution attempt: you filtered the *full* collection, `$results`, in each `foreach` loop iteration, instead of filtering *cumulatively* (excluding `Team1` first, and then excluding `Team3` *from that already filtered list*). In effect, only the *last* team specified, `Team3`, was therefore excluded from the list.

Comment: Thanks heaps! That works perfectly, however for some reason its not letting me iterate over $teamsExcluded (using foreach). I need to to be able to do that so I can insert individual HTML tags to each value - any ideas?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this again, I had a mind blank before but this works perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ayushlal; my pleasure.